# Image not found in paperclip (No route match [Get])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using paperclip for image upload:
I am getting the error:

```
Started GET "/assets/audios/thumbnails/7/thumb/4_X_4.jpg?1345530644"
for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-21 12:03:04 +0530
Served asset /audios/thumbnails/7/thumb/4_X_4.jpg - 404 Not Found (1ms)<br/>
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/audios/thumbnails/7/thumb/4_X_4.jpg"):<br/>
```

In my model as:

```
has_attached_file :thumbnail,
:styles => {:medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>"},
:url => "assets/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
:path => ":rails_root/assets/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Following link may help you:
[Upload image using paperclip](http://gkunwar1.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/how-to-upload-file-using-paperclip-in-rails/)

Comment: Please don't answer questions with just a link. Also, link doesn't contain information pertinent to the actual problem, an assertion supported by vidur's own answer.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
:url => "assets/...",
:path => ":rails_root/assets/..."
```

should be

```
:url => "/assets/...",
:path => ":rails_root/public/assets/..."
```

Although it's a terrible idea to save attachments in the assets dir. You can have another, like `files` inside `public`:

```
:url => "/files/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
:path => ":rails_root/public/files/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

Saving inside `public/files` and using `/files` url will make the webserver hit the files before rails (of course, correctly configuring your web server, e.g. nginx, is another issue)

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct solution after searching on web continuously. I tried to handle this problem by all probabilities which I could think of like:- permissions, correcting paths,changing server from webrick to thin. Then I studied about the environments properties.
So, here is the correct answer inside your Production environment set:

```
  config.serve_static_assets = true
```

This solved the problem.

Comment: This is a major server speed and potential server security issue. I wish I could find another way.